# Description of $\operatorname{Gal}(K(E[n])/K)$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ for a CM elliptic curve $E$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

I am looking for a specific description of the Galois groups $\operatorname{Gal}(K(E[n])/K)$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ for an elliptic curve $E$ with complex multiplication from an imaginary quadratic field $K$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that is divisible by primes of bad reduction.

To this end, we denote $\rho_{E,n}:\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ the Galois representation induced by the action of the absolute Galois group on the $n$-torsion subgroup $E[n]$. So we are essentially trying to describe the image of $\rho_{E,n}$ restricted to $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/K)$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. So, I looked into A. Lozano-Robledo's paper on [Galois representations attached to elliptic curves with complex multiplication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02584v3) where one can only find the specific description for primes $p$ of bad reduction in Theorem $8.1$ and Theorem $9.3$.

Moreover, I also looked into the paper of F. Campagna and R. Pengo on [Entanglement in the family of division fields of elliptic curves with complex multiplication](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.00883v3) where it is mentioned in Theorem $1.1$ that these Galois groups can be decomposed into direct products as follows:
$\operatorname{Gal}(K(E_{tors})/K)\cong\operatorname{Gal}(K(E[S^{\infty}])/K)\times\prod\limits_{p\notin S}\operatorname{Gal}(K(E[p^{\infty}])/K)$ where $E_{tors}=\bigcup\limits_{n\ge1}E[n]$ and $S$ is as defined in Theorem $1.1$. When $S$ contains just one element or, when $E$ satisfies Theorem $1.3$ there are only a handful of curves as mentioned in Table $1$ on page no. $27$ that satisfies $\operatorname{Gal}(K(E[n])/K)\cong\prod\limits_i\operatorname{Gal}(K(E[p_i^{k_i}])/K)$ where $p_i^{k_i}\mid n$. Then using A. Lozano-Robledo's paper one can find the exact subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ when $n$ is divisible by the primes $p$ of bad reduction. But what can we do for CM elliptic curves not in Table $1$?

So, has there been any work that could be helpful in this regard? Basically, I want the exact subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ corresponding to the Galois group given by the set $S$ containing the primes of bad reduction of $E$.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could provide any leads.